# Regex to parse the first letter of each line?

Tags: regex, lua

This is the list:

```
Work
Work
Fire
Global
```

And I want to extract the string `WWFG` from it. `[(?).*\n]` just give me `Global`. What should I rather be using?

For context, I'm using Rainmeter's webparser plugin.

Comment: See [Perl compatible regular expression](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/options#RegExp) mentioned in the Rainmeter docs for WebParser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?siU)(?(?=.)(.))(?(?=.*\n).*\n(.))(?(?=.*\n).*\n(.))(?(?=.*\n).*\n(.))
```

[Answered by @moshi here.](http://rainmeter.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14110) And it works perfectly with Rainmeter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `(?simU)^(.)`
RainRegExp seems to lack the replacement feature, so it is impossible to get all the captures concatenated into one string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the multiline flag with an `anchor`. I would use: `/^(.)/gm` (syntax differs from language to language)

See example here: http://regex101.com/r/uC1gV5

Comment: This doesn't work seem to work in [what I'm using](http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/plugins/webparser)...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way depends on what language you're using, but you want to replace

```
(.).*\n
```

with

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what language you're using, but here's some Python!

```
>>> import re
>>> ''.join(re.findall("(.).*", "Work\nWork\nFire\nGlobal"))
'WWFG'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will capture the first character from each line

```
([a-z])[^\n]+\n*
```

the replace with `\1` or `$1`

Depending on what is in the text you might need to change `[a-z]` to something more all-encompassing

Comment: `^([a-z])[^\n]+\n*` should be `^([a-z])[^\n]+`..no need of `\n*`

Comment: Depends if you want to return the characters all on one line or on separate lines. The OP showed them all together on one line.

Comment: `\n*` is **not** needed..that means match `\n` 0 to many times..this doesnt make sense since `[^\n]+` would reach to the character preceding `\n`..

Comment: `\n` doesn't have to exist to use `[^\n]+` which means `any character except \n`, not `any character up to \n`

Comment: @garyh I don't know if it's what I'm using but [this just gives me `F`](http://i.imgur.com/Af7df.png)

Comment: @diggthepoo what are you using?

Comment: @garyh I've updated the question. I'm Using Rainmeter's webparser. So I think it's Lua programming language.

Answer (score 0):

If that is Lua, try `s:gsub("(.).-\n","%1")`.